# Linux memory management and cpu capacity management

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I dont understand this. In early days i had one CPU, a 233 Mhz Pentium CPU with a 512 K cache, i had 64 MB of RAM. I was able to play, watch videos, got Windows working, and was able to read text data of 30MBs.
Nowadays, I got a eight core AMD CPU with 4Ghz CPUs with different Level caches up to 8MiB, got 24 GB RAM, and im not able to read a 27.5MB text without lagging.

I got this console script, calculating the residual values from x=1 to N=P1*P2-1 ( p1=1555n, p2=1945n) y(x)=x^12 % N, and building two text tables.
One has size 22.5MB, the other has size 55.9MB

```
'use strict';
var columns=12, p1=1555n, p2=1945n, N=p1*p2,   //-- modulus N=p1*p2
    e=12n, N_L=N.toString().length,            //-- exponent -> x^e % N , 0 < x < N
    x, xx_R, R, R_int, j, RvX_Collector=[], notFound=0n, commas,
    RvXcheck="", multiples="", RE_comma=new RegExp(",","g"),
    line="\u253C".padStart(N_L+3,"\u2500"), table_head, output="";

//-- building table head
table_head="X".padEnd(N_L+1," ")+" \u2502 ";
for (j=0;j<columns;j++) table_head+=(j+1).toString().padStart(2," ").padEnd(N_L," ")+" ";
table_head=table_head.slice(0,-1)+"\n"+line.padEnd(table_head.length-1,"\u2500")+"\n"; line="";
output=table_head;

//-- building RV table body
for (x=1;x<N;x++)
    {
    R=1n; xx_R=BigInt(x);
    for (j=Number(e);j>0;j=j>>1)
        {
        if (j&1) R=(R*xx_R)%N
        if (j!=1) xx_R=(xx_R*xx_R)%N
    }
    R_int=Number(R);
    if (RvX_Collector[R_int] === undefined) RvX_Collector[R_int]=x;
    else RvX_Collector[R_int]+=", "+x;
    line+=R_int.toString().padStart(N_L,"0")+" ";

    if (x%columns==0)
        {
        output+="+"+(x-columns).toString().padStart(N_L," ")+" \u2502 "+line.slice(0,-1)+"\n";
        line="";
        }
    }
if (line)
    {
    j=x%columns; if (j==0) j=columns;
    output+="+"+(x-j).toString().padStart(N_L," ")+" \u2502 "+line.slice(0,-1)+"\n";
    }

//-- building RvXcheck -> Not Found RV table, multiples string
line="";
for (j=1;j<N;j++)
    {
    if (RvX_Collector[j] == undefined) { notFound++; line+=j.toString().padStart(N_L,"0")+" "; }
    else
        {
        line+=("").padStart(N_L+1," "); 
        if (RvX_Collector[j].constructor===String)
            {
            commas=RvX_Collector[j].match(RE_comma);
            multiples+=("("+(commas.length+1)+")").toString().padStart(N_L+2," ")+" RV "+(j).toString().padStart(N_L," ")+ " at X "+RvX_Collector[j]+"\n";
            }
        }

    if (j%columns==0)
        {
        RvXcheck+="+"+(j-columns).toString().padStart(N_L," ")+" \u2502 "+line.slice(0,-1)+"\n";    
        line="";
        }
    }
if (line)
    {
    x=j%columns; if (x==0) x=columns;
    RvXcheck+="+"+(j-x).toString().padStart(N_L," ")+" \u2502 "+line.slice(0,-1)+"\n";
    }

//-- finalize information
output="Residual Values Table: x**"+e+" % "+N+" , ("+(N-notFound-1n)+") different\n\n"+output;                                                //-- add RV table title
if (!multiples) RvXcheck="unique complete residual values!"
else 
   { 
   multiples=("Multiples: \n").padEnd(22,"\u2500")+"\n"+multiples;                                                                            //-- add multiples title
   RvXcheck="Not Found Residual Values Table: ("+notFound+") missing\n\n"+"RV"+table_head.slice(2,table_head.length)+RvXcheck+"\n"+multiples; //-- add Not Found RV table title
    }

multiples=null; commas=null; 
console.log (output);
console.log (RvXcheck);
```

I gave Firefox the priority of very high.
okay calculation takes some time -> accepted.
But than, when i want to read the output, the whole thing is lagging.
I tried to copy the text into XED, but it is lagging too, even, if i put the priority of very high to the process.
When i watch the whole action in system monitor, i see that one CPU is working at 100% while the others are sleeping and 5.8 GB of the 24 GB are used.
How can i tell the kernel, that it should wake up the other CPUS, because i didnt buy them for sleeping, to do the job, keeping one cpu free for the operating system.

How can i read a 55.9MB text without lagging when scrolling.

thx in advance.

Comment: so, don't use a browser to look at text. Yes, they're inefficient at that, to a degree. Actually, they're *incredibly* efficient at displaying text, but the requirement is effectively that they render the whole document in one go. You're simply trying to force a model onto your text that is very unsuitable for displaying large amounts of text. Anything *but* a browser would be wiser.

Comment: @Marcus Müller i put the text into xed, but thats lagging too. Im on linux mint. What text application would you recommand?

Comment: Having eight cores doesn't help you do *one thing* quickly, unless that one thing is specifically written/engineered to be multithreaded.  It helps you do eight things simultaneously quickly.  And the fastest CPU in the world won't speed up a disk-bound operation.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' displaying a 5.7 MB file is not disk-bound, though, or else it be done in milliseconds

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza start with your terminal; `less largefilename.txt`; how performant is that?

Comment: @Marcus Müller why does he say disk-bound operation, what does that mean? i never saved the text to disk, i use the clipboard and copy paste it to xed, i stopped the time. I'm only able to copy it, when i use chromium, i had no chance with firefox, because of the enorme lagging. when i copied it in chromium and click on paste in xed i stopped the time. it tooks 25 seconds til it shows up in xed. I download a 55MB file faster than this time. i will now save it to a text file and try less

Comment: The clipboard might actually pose additional restrictions, not too familiar with how that works. Why are you running this strange javascript in a browser instead of with, say, node? (note that neither browsers' javascript engines nor the logging console are in any way optimized for logging massive amounts of text to console. You're using the wrong tools from start to finish…)

Comment: @Marcus Müller okay less is super, that works. its very fast. I tried to copy the whole text with the clipboard into terminal ```echo "text...."```, that crashed my terminal. saving the whole thing to a text file and use less works. Why i use a browser?  Im learning in the moment RSA, and want to examine such a Residual Value table, if there are multiples of residual values for the different x, and open a browser console and paste some javascript is easy. i dont have node installed. I didnt know that showing a 50 MB text would cause such problems.

Comment: node is not the only way you can run javascript directly instead of in a browser, but it's the one most people are familiar with. That's the only reason I mention it. No, runnig Javascript in a browser console isn't "easy"; it's awkward as hell! Get yourself a javascript development environment.